# Loop through column A and copy values in matching sheet on different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks, where workbook 1 has a list of names in column A and each name has a row of values.
Workbook 2 has worksheets labeled with names as well. Some of these name are the same as the list of names in column A of workbook 1.

What I am trying to achieve is to check if the name in column A matches the worksheet name. If yes, I want to copy the values in that row and paste them into specific cells in the sheet on workbook 2.
The code I have below works fine if every name in column A has a corresponding sheet in workbook 2 in the same order. However, I want it to be able to skip blank spaces or skip names that do not have a sheet in workbook 2. So I have added an if statement to see if that solves the problem, but that did not work. I'm getting the error: 'Application-defined or object-defined error', highlighting the if statement.

The original working code didn't have the IF statement. It worked as long as there were no spaces in the column A and every single name had a matching sheet in the same order.

I have also tried adding the error resume next lines but that just stopped triggering the error code. It copy/pasted the first row into the correct cells, but then nothing for the rest.

```
Sub Measures()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("November Stream 1 v2.xlsm")
Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
Set Rng = Sht.Range("A7:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each cell In Rng
Set ws = wb2.Sheets(cell.Text)

If wb1.Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & i) = wb2.Sheet.Name Then

   Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value
        Case "green"  '
        ws.Range("B29").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        ws.Range("B33").Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        ws.Range("B37").Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        ws.Range("B40").Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        ws.Range("B44").Value = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        
        Case "red"
        ws.Range("B47").Value = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        ws.Range("B51").Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        ws.Range("B54").Value = cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        ws.Range("B60").Value = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
        ws.Range("B65").Value = cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
        
        Case "blue"
        ws.Range("B68").Value = cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
        ws.Range("B74").Value = cell.Offset(0, 14).Value
        ws.Range("B76").Value = cell.Offset(0, 15).Value
      End Select
        End If
        
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: `wb2.sheet.name` is not valid syntax. You need to reference which sheet you are targeting i.e. `wb2.sheets("SheetName").name`

Comment: I see. What I was trying to do is make it check if the sheet name is same as the name on the list of names of workbook 1. if yes then proceed to the "case", if not then check the next name on the list and see if there is a sheet with the same name. So I don't have a specific sheet name to put. Hope that made sense, thanks

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do but it will be as you set it to that value a on the line before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to be testing for is sheet existence rather then whether the sheet matches the name that you set it to. Have a look at the following, I've tidied it up a bit and used error handling to 'test' if the sheet that you set the name to exists

```
Sub Measures()
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
    Dim cell

    Set wb2 = Workbooks("November Stream 1 v2.xlsm")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
        Set Rng = .Range("A7:A" & .cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each cell In Rng
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set ws = wb2.Sheets(cell.Value2)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value2
                Case "green"
                    ws.Range("B29").Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    ws.Range("B33").Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    ws.Range("B37").Value = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    ws.Range("B40").Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    ws.Range("B44").Value = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value

                Case "red"
                    ws.Range("B47").Value = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    ws.Range("B51").Value = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                    ws.Range("B54").Value = cell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                    ws.Range("B60").Value = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value
                    ws.Range("B65").Value = cell.Offset(0, 11).Value

                Case "blue"
                    ws.Range("B68").Value = cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                    ws.Range("B74").Value = cell.Offset(0, 14).Value
                    ws.Range("B76").Value = cell.Offset(0, 15).Value
            End Select
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no error code and its not copying anything over either

Comment: Sorry - just noticed the wrong value was setting the sheet name. Try now

Comment: Thank you, this works, but there is another issue now. Instead of copying the values on the same row as the name, its copying the value from the row directly below it for all of the names. I don't know if this is because the row values directly below has no name in column A. For example: Cell A7 has name "Jack", and I want to copy values in row 7 (cell B7 onwards), Cell A8 is blank, but there are values from Cell B8 onwards, and these are the values being copied. Removing the rows with blank name solves this, but I have 100s of blank cells in column A, with values in the row adjacent to it.

Comment: Ah - as you've got blank cells the sheet is staying set to the previous row for a blank cell. I've updated the above to reset the sheet to nothing before trying to set it again. This should cope with the blanks cells in the column as well now

Answer (score -2):

Try looping through each worksheet in wb2 and compare their names to the current cell in wb1

As psuedo (this is a rough idea, I don't have time to type it in full at current, sorry)

```
for each cell. wb1.range("your range)
    wb2.activate
    for each worksheet in wb2
        if activesheet.name = cell.value then
            'do stuff
        else
            'do nothing
        end if
    next worksheet
next cell
```

Comment: This is full of errors. Also, you don't need the `Activate` statement it is just an unnecessary overheard nor do you need two loops to be able to do this. This will also fall over if the user manages to interact with the workbook whilst it is running.

Comment: Hence why I mentioned this was simply a rough idea - given more item i would have tested something and have it working.

Comment: I'm more making a point to the basic syntax errors. Your loop should be declared as `for each cell In wb1.range("your range")` You're missing both the `In` and the closing `"`. Also, you don't need the `wb2.Activate` - it doesn't do anything. and you should use `worksheet` instead of `ActiveSheet` as your loop currently doesn't progress through the sheets. Instead it just tests whether the `ActiveSheet` name is equal to the `Cell.value` for the number of times of worksheets there are in `wb2`